# Edit DropDownList in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileLogic logic = new OpenFileLogic();
        DeliverySheetDetail deliverySheet = null;
        if(filename == OpenFileCommonCode.CREATED_FROM_BILL)
        {
            deliverySheet = logic.getBillFile_DeliveryEdit(code);
            TbCreateDate.Text = deliverySheet.CreateDate;
            TbTitle.Text = deliverySheet.Title;
            TbSpecialNote.Text = deliverySheet.SpecialNote;
            GridDeliverablesSheets.DataSource = deliverySheet.WorkDetails;
            GridDeliverablesSheets.DataBind();
        }
    }
  protected void GridDeliverablesSheets_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileLogic logic =new OpenFileLogic();
        if(e.Row.RowType ==DataControlRowType.DataRow )
        {
          DropDownList ddlNumberUnit = (DropDownList) e.Row.FindControl("DdlNumberUnit") ;
                ddlNumberUnit.DataSource = logic.getNumberUnitData();                          
                ddlNumberUnit.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlNumberUnit.DataValueField = "Code";
                ddlNumberUnit.DataBind();                                   
        }
    }
  public List<NumberUnit> getNumberUnitData()
    {
        List<NumberUnit> nUnit = new List<NumberUnit>();
        using (DBAccess dbaccess = new DBAccess())
        {
            dbaccess.OpenConnection();
            nUnit = dbaccess.GetNumberUnit();
        }
        return nUnit;
    }
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox style="text-align:right" ID="TbQuantity" Width="40px"   runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>' />
       <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlNumberUnit" runat="server">
       </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

In this code I am displaying DropDown list values which I am getting from getNumberUnitData() method. But when I want to load particular data into gridview I am not able to do it. In Page_Load method delivery.WorkDetails contains "Data" object which I want to display in the DropDown list.

Comment: In what way you will be loading a particular data as all we can see is a normal load which populate data gridview with initial data.

Answer (score 1):

I guess maybe you need to add POSTBACK

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
     // First time to run your code
   }
}
```

Comment: I added some code into this object  NumberUnitData = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Data");

                    if (NumberUnitData == null)
                    {
                        ddlNumberUnit.SelectedItem.Text = "";
                    }

Answer (score 0):

```
object  NumberUnitData = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Data");

                if (NumberUnitData == null)
                {
                    ddlNumberUnit.SelectedItem.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlNumberUnit.SelectedItem.Text = NumberUnitData.ToString();
                }
```

I added this code below  ddlNumberUnit.DataBind(); It worked.